# nodejs express router doesn't catch get request to /mypage.html

Tags: node.js, express, routes, url-routing

My goal is

1. To print a message to my console when a user enters a specific page
2. To make it possible to access a page without having to write the .html extension.

If i use the following, where test.html is not an existing page, i will see
the expected message in my console when the user tries to access `/test` or `/test.html` page.

```
router.get(/^\/test(\.html)?$/, async (req, res) => {
    console.log('User trying to access test.html page')
    res.send('welcome to test page')
})
```

But if i do the same for an existing page (`/dashboard.html`)

```
router.get(/^\/dashboard(\.html)?$/, async (req, res) => {
     console.log('User trying to access dashboard.html page')
     res.send('welcome to dashboard page')
})
```

I will see the expected message in my console when the user tries to access `/dashboard` but when he tries to access `/dashboard.html` the page will just load without seeing any message in my console.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Add your code for setting up the express server. Before this router.

Comment: I've already done that. These routes are in `src/routers/user.js` where at the bottom i use `module.exports = router` and then in `src/index.js` i include `const userRouter = require('./routers/user')`  and then `app.use(userRouter)`

Comment: I can't see it in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are telling your app to use the static files before you tell your app to use your router.

I mean, if you do this (let´s say we have in the public folder the dashboard.html file):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const port = 3000;

router.get(/^\/test(\.html)?$/, async (req, res) => {
  console.log("User trying to access test.html page");
  res.send("welcome to test page");
});

router.get(/^\/dashboard(\.html)?$/, async (req, res) => {
  console.log("User trying to access dashboard.html page");
  res.send("welcome to dashboard page");
});

app.use("/", router);

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

It should work as you expected.

However it seems you are placing the app.use(express.static...) before the app.use router. Something like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));

router.get(/^\/test(\.html)?$/, async (req, res) => {
  console.log("User trying to access test.html page");
  res.send("welcome to test page");
});

router.get(/^\/dashboard(\.html)?$/, async (req, res) => {
  console.log("User trying to access dashboard.html page");
  res.send("welcome to dashboard page");
});

app.use("/", router);


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

So in this case when you type the exact path for the dashboard.html it won´t use the router to resolve the content and it will simply take it from the public folder.

It is just a matter of order for the app.uses(...) in the code